How to Add Horizontal Scroll to Legend in Plotly Dash?
I'm working with Plotly and Dash to create a stacked area chart, and I need the legend to have a fixed width with horizontal scrolling. I have a large number of legend items, and I want to avoid the legend wrapping to the next line, instead enabling a horizontal scroll bar.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
area_empilhada_year = px.area(df_tax_year, x='year', y='value', color=tax)

grafico_area_empilhada = go.Figure()

for trace in area_empilhada_dict[tax]['ano'].data:
        if trace.name == 'sem classificação':
            trace.visible = 'legendonly'
        grafico_area_empilhada.add_trace(trace)
        grafico_area_empilhada.data[-1].visible = False
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('graph', 'figure'),     
     Output('output', 'children')],
    [Input('tax-selector', 'value'),
     Input('time-selector', 'value'),]
def update_figure(tax_selection, time_selection, line_tax_selection):
    output_text = f'Selecionado: {tax_selection} - {time_selection} {line_tax_selection}'
    # area_empilhada_dict have all graph for all tax
    figure_to_return = area_empilhada_dict[tax_selection][time_selection]
    
    return figure_to_return,output_text

I want the legend to appear in a single line and have a horizontal scrollbar if it exceeds the fixed width.
Is there a way to achieve this in Plotly and Dash?
PS: Suggestions including Dash-specific solutions are also welcome.
Current Graph Screenshot:

I tried updating the legend configuration in Plotly Dash to have a fixed width and enable horizontal scrolling. I expected the legend to appear in a single line with a scrollbar if it exceeded the fixed width. However, the legend items still wrapped to the next line instead of enabling horizontal scrolling.

